# Function reference FuncName@Number, what does @X mean?

Tags: c++, compilation

I was recently coding something using WinSock and when I tried to call WSAStartup, the compiler threw this error :

> undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8'

I have dealt with this kind of problems before, they are not a big deal, I must have missed a definition or something. However, this thread is addressed to a different subject: *What does the @8 mean?*

If you ever try to compile a file without the main function, it throws:

> undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

Again, the infamous @Number. I tried to look it up online, but honestly I don't know where to start, because all I end up getting are solutions to the compiler error, nothing related to the origin of the @16, or @8, or @X.

Another thing that I've been wondering, is what's up with the quotes:

> **`something'**

Why is the starting quote different from the ending one? and whats the point of using the backtick ( **`** ) in the first place?

Comment: I'm assuming you're not trying to solve the symbol issues, but you really want to know what it means, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly!!!

Comment: If I remember correctly @Number is how many bytes are going to be pushed on the stack. Do a websearch for calling convention.

Comment: [Decorated names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56h2zst2.aspx)

Comment: The backtick emulates the opening quote while the norml quote ia meant to be the closing quote. This is all well if your font have these two character symmetrical like this `like this ``see?´´ here` which probably was the original intent of charset designers. Unfortunately most monospace font use a simple vertical quote symbol and backwards-leaning backtick, which makes `this ``quoting style''` look godawful ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number is the bytes of it's function parameters.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679311(v=vs.85).aspx):

> For __stdcall functions, names include the "@" character and a decimal number that specifies the number of bytes in its function parameters. For example, the decorated name of the LoadLibrary function is LoadLibrary@4. For C++ functions the name decoration is more complex and varies from compiler to compiler.

Comment: I won't tell you... this was just one Google.

Comment: The problem I had was that I didint know exactly what to look for

Comment: I would appreciate if you set the answer as accepted.

Comment: the site doesnt allow an answer to be accepted within the first minutes of the question release, but your answer is indeed satisfactory